# using boost::asio to asynchronous read from multiple ports

Tags: boost-asio

Is it possible to receive packets asynchronously from multiple ports using `boost::asio` or we have to use different instances? can we do it using single thread? any link/sample code would be helpful. I want to read from `UDP` ports.
I create my socket connection using `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);`.

Comment: Have you checked boosts async udp examles, for example [async_udp_echo_server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp)?

Comment: @tkausl I have gone through examples where they have used single port. but didn't find with multiple.

Comment: `udp::endpoint()` does not accept multiple ports.

Comment: Create multiple endpoints, read from all of them async.

Comment: `udp::socket()` constructor accepts only single endpoint. or even `bind()` how to use multiple endpoints?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp do i have to create multiple server objects like `server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1])); server s1(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));` in given link? which means create 2 different sockets?

Comment: Yes, this should work.

Comment: @tkausl does it create multiple thread internally?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know how many threads ASIO creates internally.

Comment: @debonair the crux of async io is that you can do many simultaneous IO chains on a fixed number of threads (usually just 1. I know some API's need async simulation on some platforms because there is no native async API (in all versions)). Still, that would be at most 1 thread for the service, which would support all instances of that service

Comment: @tkausl @sehe so if i am creating multiple sockets, for async_read() i will have to call them in a loop sequentially? `while(true){ async_read_for_scoket1(); async_read_for_socket2();...}` aren't we loosing packets here, or what am I missing here ?

Comment: You don't read in a loop. You read once at the beginning and then each time your callback is called. Everything is handled internally by ASIO, you only need one thread running the io_service.

Comment: @tkausl but then my handler should again call `async_read_for_scoket() ` right?. that's what i meant.

Comment: Yes, these calls are "read something _once_" functions. So after ASIO calls your handler with the data, you need to start a new read.